# Finding the average of corresponding values by zipping

Tags: scala, coding-style

My goal is to make a list that contains the average values of corresponding elements from two other lists. For example, given the lists

```
val a = List[Double](1, 2)
val b = List[Double](3, 4)
```

I would like to create the list `(2, 3)`. My trouble isn't that I can't find a strategy that works, but rather that I'm finding too many strategies and can't determine which one would be best practice. Here is what I have found so far.

```
// Strategy 1
a.zip(b).map(pair => (pair._1 + pair._2) / 2)

// Strategy 2
a.zip(b).map { case (an, bn) => (an + bn) / 2 }

// Strategy 3
(a, b).zipped.map((an, bn) => (an + bn) / 2)

// Strategy 4
(a, b).zipped.map(_ / 2 + _ / 2)
```

Strategy 4 seems the cleanest to me, but it makes me nervous because

```
(a, b).zipped.map((_ + _) / 2)
```

seems very similar, but gives the error

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
```

which I don't really understand.

I understand that people will likely disagree on which solution would be the cleanest, but I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to build good habits that produce readable code.

To summarize: which strategy do you think is cleanest (possibly including one that I haven't come up with), and why does the last example give an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see these are very similar approaches, so in the end it is a matter of taste. Note that variant 1 and 2 are essentially the same, variant 2 just uses a pattern match to take the tuple apart.

So basically you have `(a zip b).map` versus `(a, b).zipped.map`. Now you find the `zipped` variant more "clean". Technically this produces a `Tuple2Zipped`, and I personally think that this approach should be discouraged. While it allows you to benefit from a bit of simpler syntax, namely that `map` uses a `Function2` instead of a `Function1[Tuple2[...]]`, this type is totally outside the regular Scala collections type hierarchy, so sooner or later you will run into lots of inconsistencies when trying to do anything non-trivial with `Tuple2Zipped`.

I would therefore strongly recommend variant 2 which you can write a bit more symmetrical with infix operator:

```
(a zip b).map { case (an, bn) => (an + bn) / 2 }
```

Comment: P.S. Good question regarding the type inferencer giving up on `(_ + _) / 2`. I have [asked myself that question now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284293/type-inference-failing-on-a-function2-argument-using-underscores)

Comment: I think it has to do with `+`. When `_ / 2 + _ / 2`, the numeric inference can be made from `_/2`

Comment: @UmNyobe I don't think so. Because you can write `_ + _ / 2` which works, although it's not mathematically what you want. Instead it seems to have to do with the extra parentheses.