# Type inference failing on a `Function2` argument using underscores

Tags: scala, type-inference

Why does the type inferencer give up on this:

```
def test(a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) = (a, b).zipped.map((_ + _) / 2)   // no
```

Like so:

```
<console>:35: error: missing parameter type for expanded function 
              ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
       def test(a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) = (a, b).zipped.map((_ + _) / 2)
                                                               ^
```

This is a strange subtlety which seems to have to do with the parentheses. For example, without using infix syntax it works:

```
def test(a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) = (a, b).zipped.map(_.+(_) / 2)   // yes
```

If I add another pair of parentheses for the fun of it, it fails again:

```
def test(a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) = (a, b).zipped.map((_.+(_)) / 2)   // no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember where in SLS it is written, but lambda desugares to the closest scope. `Map` expects a function `(Int, Int) => B`, so when you write `map(_.+(_) / 2)` it is desugared into what is expected. But in the case of `((_ + _) / 2)` or `((_.+(_)) / 2)` your lambda is desugared into `(((x, y) => x + y) / 2)`, basically you're trying to devise a function by 2 and that's why Scalac can't infer types